# How does cargo resolve conflicting dependency versions?

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo

I have started to work on this open source [repo](https://github.com/dojoengine/dojo).

I don't understand how cargo resolves the deps because the [Cargo.toml](https://github.com/dojoengine/dojo/blob/7183570b3ffc164ca8ab939c2eede62f94a147ad/Cargo.toml#L51) pins `cairo-vm = "0.5.1"` but their [`blockifier` dependency](https://github.com/dojoengine/dojo/blob/7183570b3ffc164ca8ab939c2eede62f94a147ad/Cargo.toml#L83) pins [0.3.0](https://github.com/dojoengine/blockifier/blob/6c3efcc4d12a39c28921b3e4fad31d753a52cc45/Cargo.toml#L14).

Consequently in the [`Cargo.lock`](https://github.com/dojoengine/dojo/blob/7183570b3ffc164ca8ab939c2eede62f94a147ad/Cargo.lock#L2140) the resolved version is 0.3.0 without any warning.

In other words, when pinning a version for crate `A` in `Cargo.toml` but crate `B` depends on `A` with another pinned version, how does `cargo` resolve it?

I'm coming from python where, for instance, poetry would raise with "non compatible dependencies". How to have this kind of message with cargo? Or what am I missing?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong branch of `blockifier`. The dependency in dojo patches it with the `dev` branch where [the 0.3.0-rc1 dependency](https://github.com/dojoengine/blockifier/blob/6c3efcc4d12a39c28921b3e4fad31d753a52cc45/Cargo.toml#LL14C1-L14C23) is specified.

Comment: It's quite possible to have multiple versions of the same dependency in a single project. This works fine as long as you don't mix their usage, i.e. you can't pass an instance of `version1::Foo` to a function that expects a `version2::Foo`, and you will get a rather obscure error message if you try.

Comment: @Jmb that's true, but then you'd still see both versions of the dependency in `Cargo.lock`, no?

Comment: @isaactfa yes, my comment was an answer to the comparison with Python where conflicting dependencies raise an error from the start.

Comment: @Jmb Ah I gotcha.

Comment: @isaactfa indeed `blockifier` is patched and specified 0.3.0-rc1, but the cargo.toml of `dojo` repo also requires 0.5.1, ie that the same file says:
```
cairo-vm = "0.5.1"
blockifier = { git = "https://github.com/dojoengine/blockifier", branch = "dev" }
```
and `blockifier/dev` says 0.3.0-rc1

Comment: @ClementWalter note that none of the workspace crates actually use the `cairo-vm` dependency. So basically the workspace `Cargo.toml` says: "**If** a workspace crate says that it depends on `cairo-vm`, then that means version 0.5.0," but since none of the workspace crates depend on `cairo-vm` that dependency is ignored.